# Content Add-In instance ID

Tags: office-js

I am trying to make a Map Addin. Ideally I want to be able to display many maps to a user at any one time, each with it's own dataset. Ideally I want the user to be able to permanently define the location of the data for a specific addin instance.

How do I go about doing this? Is there an ID which a content add-in is assigned which is always constant? Or does a content add-in instance have some "data" which can be accessed from within OfficeJS?

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are talking about **user** clicking some button to **set** some setting **per document**, that's possible.

> Is there an ID which a content add-in is assigned which is always
>   constant? Or does a content add-in instance have some "data" which can
>   be accessed from within OfficeJS?

Well there's the ID of the add-in. This is not something you could retrieve programmatically though. Also this wouldn't really help you because you will have different users setting different settings.

What you are looking for is the Office document settings / persistence. Check out this API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/persisting-add-in-state-and-settings

Comment: Yep it seems that `Office.Settings` interface is what I needed. `Office.context.document.settings.get("data")`, `Office.context.document.settings.set("data","...your data here...")` and `Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync()`

Comment: Would you accept it as the solution if this has solved your problem?